# How to configure nuxt or a webpage so routes stay without "/" at end

Tags: nuxt.js, router

I have this problem when i start serving my app. i have everything ok on local but when i generate and serve sometimes routes adds "/" to end and that route doesnt work. it all started with getting some queries from firestore.
I had this route me.com/verify and firebase sends queries to this rouye like me.com/verify?mode...
and when i click those links they go to me.com/verify/?mode...
how can i fix this `Vue.use(Router)

export const routerOptions = {
  mode: 'history',
  base: decodeURI('/'),
  linkActiveClass: 'nuxt-link-active',
  linkExactActiveClass: 'exact-active-link',
  scrollBehavior,

routes: [{
    path: "/credits",
    component: _e06d46b8,
    name: "credits"
  }, {
    path: "/dat",
    component: _4af06e21,
    name: "dat"
  }, {
    path: "/live",
    component: _039e10ae,
    name: "live"`

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `trailingSlash` option to `false` in router configs in `nuxt.config.js`

https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-router#trailingslash

Comment: where exactly should i set it in nuxt?

Comment: if u have knowledge can u please answer what is the reason when there's parameters my app appends / to my routes which breaks my app

Comment: i.e  me.com - good  but me.com?a=b becomes me.com/?a=b and this breaks my app

Comment: because i can get the parameters if its sth.com?a=b but when it becomes sth.com/?a=b i cant get those params and also some other parts of my app stops working this happens only when i serve my app. not on local host

Comment: can this be caused by nginx? i serve static files using nginx reverse proxy